# FFMPEG drawbox filter. Hex color result not matching input values

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a border using the drawbox filter using a specific HEX color input, however the result I am getting does not match the value I set.

Consider the following code which produces a 600x600 swatch;

```
ffmpeg -i 0.jpg -vf drawbox=x=0:y=0:w=600:h=600:color=#E4E8F3@1:t=fill _border.png
```

E4E8F3 is supposed to translate to RGB 228,232,243

When I run the above code, however, and re-import into photoshop the actual color, is "sort of close", but not close enough.

The color I end up getting is;

Hex d2d7df, which is RGB 210,215,223

Any ideas why I'm not getting the result I expect?

Comment: It's a bug. The filter is designed to work on video and assumes studio range. I'll add an answer when this is patched.

Comment: For now, add `scale=in_range=pc:out_range=tv` before the drawbox.

Comment: @Gyan This does not appear to fix drawbox's colour per say. Rather it twists the entire picture's colour into matching drawbox.

Comment: Also for some reason, if drawbox is followed by a rotate with the same 'fillcolor', they will still output noticeably different colours from each others.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out... need to put RGB24 at the beginning of the filter chain, not at the end (where it does nothing in this situation)

```
ffmpeg -i 0.jpg -vf "format=rgb24,drawbox=x=0:y=0:w=600:h=600:color=#ffffff:t=fill" _border.png
```

Comment: You're getting ffmpeg to perform two conversions with this method, from YUVJ to RGB and then back to YUV. There's some rounding error possible due to this roundtrip.