# How to draw a white box on image using FFMpeg correctly

Tags: windows, filter, ffmpeg

I want to draw some white filled rectangles in a bitmap (bmp format, happens with other input formats too) and store it as JPEG (mjpeg) with FFMpeg console executable on Windows 10 64-bit.

Therefore I use the drawbox filter. If I take any color which is not "next to white", it works fine. If I try to draw white boxes I always get grey boxes. If I use another output format like PNG it works fine.

It does not matter if I use the string `White` or a hex RGB(A) format like `0xFFFFFF` or `0xFFFFFFFF`. Even colors "next to white" like `0xFEFEFE` do always result in grey color.

FFMpeg does not report any warnings or errors. I use following command line:

`ffmpeg.exe -i input.bmp -filter:v drawbox=x=10:y=10:w=100:h=100:color=0xFFFFFF:t=fill -q:v 3 -f image2 output.jpg`

I can confirm that this issue happens with the latest development version (master branch).

I am doing something wrong here or is this a bug?

OS: Win10 64-Bit, latest FFMpeg from https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ (master branch)

Comment: This is a bug and has a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601103/ffmpeg-drawbox-filter-hex-color-result-not-matching-input-values